# Material UI 1.0 beta, accent color raised button with white text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the new Material-ui 1.0, I want all my raised buttons to be the accent color of my app (#00c853) and the text on the button should be white.

```
<Button raised color="accent">Button</Button>
```

The button is now green, but the text is black and I can not manage to get the text color to be white.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button's text color is automatically determined by *Material UI* depending on the defined color palette. However, you can use a [global style override](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type) to set a new text color for the buttons:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      raisedAccent: {
        color: 'white !important'
      }
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <YourApp/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```